# Changing JFrame components in Java and ActionPerformed invocation

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

How to remove all `JFrame` components from a contentPane on Click event?

Here's the code:

```
final JButton b = new JButton("Table");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(b.getText());
        contentPane.removeAll();//PRessing the button, it does not go away
    }});
contentPane.add(b);
```

If I use `contentPane.removeAll();` in outside of actionPerformed function

```
contentPane.removeAll();
```

then it works well

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setJMenuBar(AppViewMenu.getMenu(this));
setTitle("Simple examplesss");
setSize(500, 600);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(isVisible);
```

Thank you

Comment: Where/how is `contentPane` defined? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You need to `repaint()`/`revalidate()` after removing in order to see changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `removeAll()` method but it's not preferrable way in Swing. Much better is to provide two views which are layouted in a panel with the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and in your `ActionListener` you can switch the views.

If you still want to use `removeAll()` you should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after that.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    contentPane.removeAll();
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```